# Does the Apple EarPods exist in different shapes?

Tags: iphone, headphones

I have four sets of Apple EarPods, with remote control and volume.

I think everything has always been ok with all of them, but suddenly, I discovered a problem with one, which doesn't sound right when placed in the ears as usual.

I need to put the volume level up to hear correctly with it, and I have discovered that if I put the long white part a bit up, rotating the headphone in the ear, I manage to make it sound better.

My questions are:

1. Are there different versions of the EarPods which would fit differently in the ears (I don't see any difference but maybe it's too small or only in the headphone design)?
2. If not, what could be the reason the volume is better when I move the EarPod differently? (Maybe it isn't working perfectly anymore and only a part of the headphone still send music?)

Comment: If this is a sudden problem, are you sure the problem is not you? blocked or partially blocked ear canal etc...

Comment: I downvoted this because, at minimum, basic research on the Apple website would tell you there aren’t any other versions of the AirPods and that there are three different sizes of silicone tips

Comment: Additionally, EarPods (and virtually every other earbud on the market) will change the sound quality based on how you have them in your ears. They sound better because they seal better in your ear canal when you adjust them properly. This has been the case for two decades now.

Comment: Allan, can you read the question before downvoting ? I'm talking about EarPods only.

Comment: And about the adjustment in the ear, why does it work perfectly with one set and not with another ?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there different versions of the EarPods which would fit differently in the ears ...

All Apple AirPods come in the same size but, unlike Apple AirPods, [Apple AirPods Pro](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/) come in three different sizes in ear tips. Because they are of different sizes, those tips fit ears differently. So one of those three different pairs of tips might be able to help you get better performance than the others (and Airpods) if you would consider purchasing a pair of AirPods Pro.

[image: in the box airpod pro]

> If not, what could be the reason the volume is better ...

Slight changes in how AirPods sit in your ears may change how the sound reaches into your ear because the directions of the speakers change as you move them inside your ears. However, unless the insides of your external ears have quite distinct shapes or you usually sit close to a high volume sound source, they should sit nicely in your ears and you should not have to move them frequently / drastically to hear comfortably.

Airpods Pro may help in that regard as well, i.e. get a more consistent performance, because their tips fit relatively tightly into the entrance of ear canals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue is that i have other EarPods and they work perfectly without moving them (moving them does nothing in the sound volume). So I presume, if the shape is always the same, that they have a problem

Answer (score 1):

> Are there different versions of the EarPods which would fit differently in the ears

**No**. There is only variety and size variant of [EarPods](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug) manufactured by Apple.

One size to fit all was the original design goals, as stated by Apple in their EarPods marketing campaigns.

> If not, what could be the reason the volume is better when I move the EarPod differently?

It likely has nothing to do with the EarPod itself but with the auditory perception corresponding to the placement of the EarPod in your ear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there is only one size, I presume this set has an issue, because i have other EarPods sets which perfectly work without moving them in the ears.